# Largest subset of rectangles such that no rectangle fits in any other rectangle

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given height and width of N rectangles. The task is to find the size of the largest subset such that no pair of rectangles fit within each other. Note that if H1 ≤ H2 and W1 ≤ W2 then rectangle 1 fits inside rectangle 2.

```
Input: arr[] = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {1, 3}}
Output: 2
The required sub-set is {{1, 3}, {2, 2}}
{1, 3} is included only once as it can fit in {1, 3}

Input: arr[] = {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {1, 1}, {3, 3}}
Output: 3
```

Can someone explain me the dynamic programming intuition behind this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Lets order the input by ascending height and consider the scenarios given that we chose any one rectangle.

(1) we cannot now choose any second rectangle with the same width or height since the one with the smaller of the non-equal dimension could be contained in the one with the larger (e.g., 2×6 can be contained in 2×8, or 2x4 could be contained in 2×6)

(2) we cannot now choose any second rectangle that has both higher height and higher width since it could obviously contain the first rectangle.

Since we have ordered the rectangles by ascending height, we must therefore choose a second rectangle with greater height and smaller width, which leads to the following algorithm:

```
Order by height ascending.

Find the longest sequence of strictly
ascending height and strictly decreasing
width.
```

Comment: A simple yet elegant explanation

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what the answer will be for the second example (in my question)? It will be {1,5},{2,4},{3,3}. Right? Also is the time complexity for this solution O(N^2)?

Comment: @jamesgem yes {1,5},{2,4},{3,3} makes sense since {1,1} can fit into the others. I would imagine that we could adapt a method for finding the [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) for an O(n log n) solution.